# Spring JPA: How to force a foreign key constraint validation when using just @JoinColumn and not a full blown @ManyToOne

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, joincolumn

For example, consider the following code, when the parent doesn't reference the children but the children can reference the parent's id. A child doesn't care about the actual parent fields like the name.

```
@Entity
class Parent {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column
  String name;
}

@Entity
class Child {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column
  String name;

  // 1. For simplicity, a child can have only one parent
  // 2. Reference just the parent id - don't care about the parent's fields
  @JoinColumn(table = "parent", referencedColumnName = "id")
  long parentId;
}
```

So now, when I insert a child, without first inserting a parent, I **don't** get any "foreign key constraint violation" or as spring defines it "DataIntegrityViolationException". Example of an insert:

```
repo.save(new Child("no_god?"));
```

Tried also `foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT)`.

When I defined a full blown `@ManyToOne(optional = false)` on the child + `@OneToMany` on the parent, it works, but I want to use a simple id relationship - not full blown objects.

How to make the foreign key constraint work with a simple id reference definition?

---

Comment: If you add the constraint on the database level, it should not allow you to insert an invalid id. In that case, you can have a bare `long parentId;` without any annotations.

Comment: Thanks Toni, I'd like JPA to create the schema (DDL) for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want JPA to create your DDL but don't want to mapping them,  you can specify it

```
    @Column(columnDefintion="bigint references parent(id)")
    long parentId;
```

You need to specify it by your database specific SQL type and syntax for the constraint.

Comment: Is there a flag disable/enable to this DDL? In production, we have a long and complicated process to create the DDL and in tests I'd like a short one based on Spring.

Comment: You can set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` explicitly and the standard Hibernate property values are `none`, `validate`, `update`, `create-drop`. Set it to `none` if you don't want to auto-create. Also a file named `import.sql` in the root of the classpath will be executed on startup.